# Python - Adding python modules to .exe file compiled by py Installer on Windows

Tags: python, windows, exe, wget, pyinstaller

I wrote a simple Python script on Linux machine:

```
#!/bin/python

import wget

wget.download("<url>","/tmp)
```

And this code work well, download file from apache2 server and save it to /tmp folder

Next I changed location from "/tmp" to "C:/". I installed on my Windows machine Python, pip, pyInstaller and wget module. Now via pyInstaller I want to make .exe file which download file from server and save it to disc C:/.
I ran cmd as administrator:

```
pyInstaller "test.py"
```

output:

```
70 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
70 INFO: Python: 3.7.4
70 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
70 INFO: wrote C:\test.spec
70 INFO: UPX is not available.
70 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\', 'C:\\']
70 INFO: checking Analysis
70 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
70 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
91 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
184 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
7545 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
7559 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\tester\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
7919 INFO: Caching module hooks...
8039 INFO: Analyzing C:\test.py
8620 INFO: Loading module hooks...
8620 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
8774 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
8807 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
8983 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
8983 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
8996 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
9720 INFO: Looking for eggs
9720 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\tester\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
9720 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
9728 INFO: Warnings written to C:\build\test\warn-test.txt
9794 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\build\test\xref-test.html
9855 INFO: checking PYZ
9855 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
9855 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz
10478 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\build\test\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
10511 INFO: checking PKG
10511 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
10511 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
10531 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
10543 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\tester\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
10543 INFO: checking EXE
10543 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
10543 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
10543 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\build\test\test.exe
10616 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
10616 INFO: checking COLLECT
10636 INFO: Building COLLECT because COLLECT-00.toc is non existent
10636 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc
11835 INFO: Building COLLECT COLLECT-00.toc completed successfully.
```

When I run compiled script, nothing appears in C:/

And the question is: Am I missing something or doing something wrong? Should I add wget module manually to pyInstaller command? or I just don`t understand pyInstaller documentation and there is no way to use external modules in Windows .exe file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it is a python issue. Try to change the path to your user profile. Or run the app as administrator.

I would not recommend to save to c:\ anyway, unless you have a good reason.

Comment: Yeah, I have not access to write file in disc C:\ I changed path to user profile as you said, and It works :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The .py file is successfully converted to .exe file and the file is located in C:\dist\

There will be folder created at path C:\ and pyinstaller creates a folder with name "test" inside the "dist" folder. You can access the test.exe file from C:\dist\test\

If you want to make you executiion file in single file then in cmd  enter the command pyinstaller --onefile test.py   (test.py is the file which need to be converted to .exe)

Fore more options, read the documentation of PyInstaller